# Excel Sum If based on month of date range?

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have sheet with a list of users and their holidays taken like so:

```
Katie     1     01/01/2016
Dave      2     12/02/2016
Dave      2     12/12/2015
Katie     1     17/11/20165    
Liam      1     05/01/2016
Marie     1     09/08/2015
Marie     5     23/09/2015
```

I am then using the following SUMIF formula on my other sheet to return the total number of holidays taken for each person

```
=SUMIF(Data!A$1:A$1000,A13,Data!B$1:B$1000)
```

This gives me a result like so:

```
Katie     2
Dave      4
Liam      1
Marie     6
```

However, now I want to turn my SUMIF into a SUMIFS which only returns the values for the month of January like so:

```
Katie      1
Liam       1
```

I know I can get the month of the date by using `=TEXT('Cell Ref',"mmmm")` but I'm not sure how I would combine this into an SUMIFS statement.

Can someone please show me how I can do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use an Array Formula:

```
=SUM(IF((Data!A$1:A$1000=A13)*(Month(Data!C$1:C$1000) = 1),Data!B$1:B$1000))
```

Since it is an Array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode.  Then copied down.

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, I tried your code but it comes up with a #Value error and I'm not sure why?

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter the exit edit mode?  Are your dates actual dates or are the text in the form of dates?  To First question, when you click on the cell with the formula does the formula have `{}` on the ends?  To the second are the dates right or left justified, if it is left justified then usually this is indicative of them being text instead of a number that is formatted as a date.

Comment: Nevermind had a trailing space which was causing the problem, it works now! thanks